# Are variables commonly used in CSS?

Tags: html, css

Modern CSS gives us the possibility to use CSS variables that we can reference in multiple other places.

To what extent do they differ from the variables within JavaScript?

Am I more performant when I set CSS attributes or values via JavaScript, or the opposite is the case? Is that a chicken and egg story, or is there a proven way to do that?

Comment: Using variables is a good practice in CSS. It helps you define your website's styling in common terms and whenever you have to change any styling (for example: primary font color for the website) just change the variable value, rather than changing it everywhere.

Comment: In short, It depends. Variables are used heavily in electron applications and large websites for code readability and consistency. But in small websites they are often insignificant.

Comment: See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes, variables are generally used when you are developing something big and you don't want to repeat your reusable colors or any other properties. But if you're just starting then I don't think it necessary to use variables more. If you want you can but not necessary.
You may also find that in frameworks like bootstrap or material css variables are declared once and used in many places.

- Usage of variables makes more sense when you are using any preprocessor like Sass or less or something else.